# Custom Property in Sandboxed Visual Web Part

Tags: 2010, office-365, sandbox-solution

I would like to create a Custom Property for a Sandboxed Visual Web Part but I'm not able to do so.

**Requirement:** I would like to display data of Blog "Posts" List(RSS Feed) in Custom web part by providing the Name of a Sub Site in Custom Property of Web Part.

Answer (score 1):

To create a Custom Property for a Sandboxed Visual Web part, you can make use of the below code and link,

```
[WebBrowsable(true), Personalizable(true)]
public string ListName { get; set; }
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717096/how-to-create-a-editable-property-on-a-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-visual-webpart)

Using the above custom property value, find out the ListRssUrl and pass it to the below function to get the data from it.

Here is a small code snippet to parse sharepoint blog posts list’s Rss feed.

```
protected string GetRSS(string ListRssUrl)
{

string rss_text = “”;
string title = “”;
string link = “”;
string description = “”;

XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(ListRssUrl);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator items = nav.Select(“//item”);

while (items.MoveNext())
{
XPathNavigator navCurrent = items.Current;

title = navCurrent.SelectSingleNode(“title”).InnerXml;
link = navCurrent.SelectSingleNode(“link”).InnerXml;
description = navCurrent.SelectSingleNode(“description”).InnerXml;
}
}
```

[Source](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/01/01/programmatically-access-rss-feed-for-sharepoint-list/)

In your webpart, you can use a grid to display the title, link, description, etc.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the option explained in this post [How to create a custom property and set a default value in a SharePoint 2013 Visual WebPart](http://www.ashokraja.me/articles/How-to-create-a-custom-property-and-set-a-default-value-in-a-SharePoint-2013-Visual-WebPart)

Comment: Please, do not only provide a link. It is better if you try to summarize the content and post it here (of course with a reference to the page). Thanks, and welcome to SP.SE! :)

Comment: Also we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines. No big deal in this case, but for future reference. Welcome to the site.